# Returning data using the same column for different combinations of results in the same query

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL, trying to self teach, and struggling already with what seems to me should be a very simple query, or at least a very common one. I'm not even sure I know the lexicon to describe what I am trying to achieve, so apologies if the title of this thread turns out to be misleading! :)

I have a big database. I want to identify rows where 2 results in one column appear together, or another 2 results in the same column appear together over a set time period.

I started using `AND` but turned up zero results. I have spent the last 2-3 hours searching all over the net with limited success. There appear to be lots of similar threads that suggest `UNION`, `SELECT DISTINCT`, `JOIN`s or other solutions but I have completely failed to adapt them for my needs.

Any pointers much appreciated.

So, my table is called `VNH.dbo.ClinicalCaseItem`

Data table looks like this:

```
ActualDateTime | CaseId | ProcedureTestId | Description | FeeAmount
```

I need to limit the `ActualDateTime` to greater than `2017-04-03` or the number of entries will run into the 100s of thousands. The `ProcedureTestId` is the key column. I need to, exclusively, identify those `CaseId` with `ProcedureTestId 309` which occur together with `ProcedureTestId 245`, and those `CaseId` with `ProcedureTestId 309` which occur together with `ProcedureTestId 326`.

I won't detail all the different queries I've tried as there have been half a dozen or so and none have come close to achieving the result I need, and most have failed completely.

Many thanks in advance

Example data:

```
ActualDateTime | CaseId | ProcedureTestId | Description       | FeeAmount  
    2017-04-25 | 123456 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00   
    2017-04-25 | 123456 | 329             | GA Patient        | 100.00   
    2017-04-27 | 134523 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00   
    2017-04-27 | 234567 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00   
    2017-04-28 | 234567 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00   
    2017-04-28 | 345321 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00   
    2017-04-29 | 451324 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00   
    2017-04-30 | 451324 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00   
    2017-04-30 | 451324 | 375             | Surgical Pack     | 28.00
    2017-04-25 | 989898 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00
    2017-04-27 | 989898 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00
    2017-04-25 | 999999 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00
    2017-04-27 | 999999 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00
    2017-04-27 | 999999 | 326             | Bathe Patient     | 45.00
    2017-04-27 | 987654 | 375             | Surgical Pack     | 28.00
    2017-04-25 | 987654 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00
    2017-04-27 | 987654 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00
    2017-04-27 | 987654 | 329             | GA Patient        | 100.00
    2017-04-27 | 987654 | 326             | Bathe Patient     | 45.00
```

The expected result of the query would be:

```
ActualDateTime | CaseId | ProcedureTestId | Description       | FeeAmount | count_of  
    2017-04-25 | 123456 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00     | 2
    2017-04-25 | 123456 | 329             | GA Patient        | 100.00    | 2   
    2017-04-27 | 234567 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00     | 2  
    2017-04-28 | 234567 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00     | 2  
    2017-04-25 | 989898 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00     | 2
    2017-04-27 | 989898 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00     | 2
    2017-04-25 | 999999 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00     | 2
    2017-04-27 | 999999 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00     | 2
    2017-04-25 | 987654 | 309             | Place iv catheter | 30.00     | 3
    2017-04-27 | 987654 | 245             | Sedate Patient    | 45.00     | 3
    2017-04-27 | 987654 | 329             | GA Patient        | 100.00    | 3
```

Comment: An actual data sample would help. Question: what do you mean by "key column"? Is it primary key or foreign key?

Comment: Sorry, just mean - most important - as in the one my question hinges on.

Example data:

Comment: Sample data please and the output you want to get.

Comment: Sorry, just mean - most important - as in the one my question hinges on.

Example data:



2017-04-25 | 123456 | 309 | Place iv catheter | 30.00
2017-04-25 | 123456 | 329 | GA Patient | 100.00
2017-04-27 | 134523 | 309 | Place iv catheter | 30.00
2017-04-27 | 234567 | 245 | Sedate Patient | 45.00
2017-04-28 | 234567 | 309 | Place iv catheter | 30.00
2017-04-28 | 345321 | 245 | Sedate Patient | 45.00
2017-04-29 | 451324 | 309 | Place iv catheter | 30.00
2017-04-30 | 451324 | 309 | Place iv catheter | 30.00
2017-04-30 | 451324 | 375 | Surgical Pack | 28.00

Hope that helps

Comment: That didn't format well at all did it? Hope you can make sense of it. I'm looking to know which rows have both 309 and 329 or both 309 and 245, excluding all other results.

Comment: Edit your question and include extra info there. If you cannot get formatting right, leave as is; I or someone else will format it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Having sample data is very helpful, but unless it is coupled to an "expected result" we cannot compare any query output to that; and hence we can only invent something that might work - which is what I present below.

My interpretation of your words is that you need caseid IF the case has proceeded through at least procedures (309 and 245) or (309 and 326). Now when I compare that requirement to the sample data I cannot find any rows that meet that criteria, so I added some that do.  However also note that in the logic I have adopted any case that had procedures (245 and 326 but not 309) would also be returned.

The fundamental "trick" here (aka "method") is to use a case expression inside a SUM() function and evaluate this using a `having` clause (which permits filtering of results based on aggregated values).

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eed4/8) let's you perform your own trial queries.

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ActualDateTime] datetime, [CaseId] int, [ProcedureTestId] int, [Description] varchar(17), [FeeAmount] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ActualDateTime], [CaseId], [ProcedureTestId], [Description], [FeeAmount])
VALUES
    ('2017-04-25 00:00:00', 989898, 309, 'Place iv catheter', 30.00),
    ('2017-04-27 00:00:00', 989898, 245, 'Sedate Patient', 45.00),

    ('2017-04-25 00:00:00', 999999, 309, 'Place iv catheter', 30.00),
    ('2017-04-27 00:00:00', 999999, 245, 'Sedate Patient', 45.00),
    ('2017-04-27 00:00:00', 999999, 326, 'whatever 326 is', 45.00),

    ('2017-04-25 00:00:00', 123456, 309, 'Place iv catheter', 30.00),
    ('2017-04-25 00:00:00', 123456, 329, 'GA Patient', 100.00),
    ('2017-04-27 00:00:00', 134523, 309, 'Place iv catheter', 30.00),
    ('2017-04-27 00:00:00', 234567, 245, 'Sedate Patient', 45.00),
    ('2017-04-28 00:00:00', 234567, 309, 'Place iv catheter', 30.00),
    ('2017-04-28 00:00:00', 345321, 245, 'Sedate Patient', 45.00),
    ('2017-04-29 00:00:00', 451324, 309, 'Place iv catheter', 30.00),
    ('2017-04-30 00:00:00', 451324, 309, 'Place iv catheter', 30.00),
    ('2017-04-30 00:00:00', 451324, 375, 'Surgical Pack', 28.00)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
      select CaseId
         , sum(case when ProcedureTestId in (309,245,326) then 1 else 0 end) count_of
      from Table1
      group by CaseId
      having sum(case when ProcedureTestId in (309,245,326) then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eed4/8/0)**:

```
| CaseId | count_of |
|--------|----------|
| 234567 |        2 |
| 451324 |        2 |
| 989898 |        2 |
| 999999 |        3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select
      t.*, d.count_of
from Table1 t
inner join (
      select CaseId
         , sum(case when ProcedureTestId in (309,245,326) then 1 else 0 end) count_of
      from Table1
      group by CaseId
      having sum(case when ProcedureTestId in (309,245,326) then 1 else 0 end) > 1
      ) d on t.CaseId = d.CaseId
order by caseid, ProcedureTestId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eed4/8/1)**:

```
|       ActualDateTime | CaseId | ProcedureTestId |       Description | FeeAmount | count_of |
|----------------------|--------|-----------------|-------------------|-----------|----------|
| 2017-04-27T00:00:00Z | 234567 |             245 |    Sedate Patient |        45 |        2 |
| 2017-04-28T00:00:00Z | 234567 |             309 | Place iv catheter |        30 |        2 |
| 2017-04-29T00:00:00Z | 451324 |             309 | Place iv catheter |        30 |        2 |
| 2017-04-30T00:00:00Z | 451324 |             309 | Place iv catheter |        30 |        2 |
| 2017-04-30T00:00:00Z | 451324 |             375 |     Surgical Pack |        28 |        2 |
| 2017-04-27T00:00:00Z | 989898 |             245 |    Sedate Patient |        45 |        2 |
| 2017-04-25T00:00:00Z | 989898 |             309 | Place iv catheter |        30 |        2 |
| 2017-04-27T00:00:00Z | 999999 |             245 |    Sedate Patient |        45 |        3 |
| 2017-04-25T00:00:00Z | 999999 |             309 | Place iv catheter |        30 |        3 |
| 2017-04-27T00:00:00Z | 999999 |             326 |   whatever 326 is |        45 |        3 |
```

Comment: Notice the importance of an "expected result" (e.g. did you want the summary or the detail layout?) but also that the sample data should provide data for the "expected result" too.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting, the sample data I provided did have matching rows, but your interpretation was correct. The result from query 2 is almost what I am looking for. I need the lines CaseId without ProcedureTestId 309 excluding, and any ProcedureTestId which isn't 309, 326 or 245 excluding, so all of CaseId 451324 and the bottom row of 999999 would be excluded. I will edit my post to include your extended data table and add a results table.